# Image is not displaying on applet

Tags: java, applet

This is the code I used for displaying an image in applet.The applet is working, but not displaying the image.The image is present in the src folder.

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.applet.*;  


public class DisplayImage extends Applet {  

Image picture;  

public void init() {  
 picture = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"IMG-20160319-WA0003.jpg");  
}  

public void paint(Graphics g) {  
 g.drawImage(picture, 30,30, this);  
}  

}
```

The HTML code:

```html
     <html> 
       <HEAD>
   </HEAD>
<body>  
<applet code="DisplayImage.class" width="300" height="300">  
</applet>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: So can you confirm 2 things: 1) The image is located in the same directory of the server as the web page that loads the applet? 2) The image is that exact name, including the (upper/lower) case of the letters? BTW - 1) An unsigned class will not be loaded by a modern JRE. 2) To be signed, classes must be in a Jar. 3) .. But most browsers are removing all support for plug-ins like applets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the image is in the same folder as the `.class` file, and not the `.java` file, as the `.class` file is the one that is being executed.

A better solution still would be to create a jar containing the code and the image. The base folder of the jar I created looks as follows:

[image]

Within the applet folder you can find the `.class` files. Put the jar file in the same folder as you html file. You then have to adapt your `.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <applet archive="applet.jar" code="applet.DisplayImage.class" width="300" height="300">  
        </applet> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the image is in a Jar, it must be accessed as an [tag:embedded-resource] rather than using the usual applet methods. OTOH if the path & name is right, there is no reason the image could not be loaded direct from the server (outside the Jar).

Comment: The image was in the src folder and i copied it to the 'build' folder. Now the applet displays the image.